# How do I create a constant object in Java?

Tags: java

How do I create a reference to a constant object?

```
final Myclass obj = new Myclass();
```

does not work, it says obj(the reference) should not be re-assigned but we can still change the object referred. 
I want to ensure that the object itself does not change once constructed.

Comment: How exactly are you changing the object referenced?  Are you re-setting the value of obj?  Or are you changing the values inside of obj?  Java should not allow you to change what obj points to.  That's the meaning of a final variable.  To handle making the contents of obj immutable, you need to code an immutable class as described below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just make it immutable (like `String` is). Or wrap it in another object which restricts access to mutators of the object in question (like [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) and consorts do).

Comment: check also "favor immutability" in Effective Java: http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/attach/JavaProgramming/ej.html#immutablerecipe

Comment: @dfa: this is awesome. However, is there a links of discussion for his second books?

Answer (score 10):

You are mixing two things: final and immutable.

A variable can be **final**, so you can't change it's a value (or object reference) after it is initialized (but of course you can change the reference's objects attributes)

An object can be **immutable** (not a keyword but a property), so you can't change it's *value* after it is created. The string is a good example - you can not change the backing char[] inside a String object.

Comment: Hi. I have a question for you. for `final` when you said, `you cant change its value (or object reference) after it is initialized`, I understand that. So `final int x=10; x=11;` will generate a compiler error. But I dont understand your second statement `but of course you can change the reference's object attributes`. Can you provide a small piece of code to show me? I would greatly appreciate it. tyvm

Comment: @Harry Pham - Sounds complicated but isn't: consider a `final List l = new ArrayList()`. You can't assign another list to `l` (because it's final) but you can add objects to the list. That's *changing the lists attributes*: the wrapped array in this example.

Answer (score 9):

What you want is an [Immutable Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). There are no keywords in Java that can instantly make an object immutable. You have to design the object's logic, so that its state cannot be changed. As BalusC put, you can wrap it in another object which restricts access to its mutators.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any built in keyword to make that possible in Java. Even if the reference is constant/final, the internals of the object could still be changed.

Your best options is to have a ReadOnly implementation version of your class.

You can read more about this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#final_in_Java

Comment: It would be possible if your object is immutable to outside classes (with no setters and only private members), and you do not change the state inside the object class itself.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with read only implementation. Only make public functions that access internal but never allow changing them.

Comment: Right, but that's still possible in Java then :).

Comment: Rephrased the first bit of the reply. By not possible I meant that there was no keyword that would give it this behavior like in C++ for instance. All fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, an immutable class is generally means that it doesn't have "setters" and any field that can be accessed with a "getter" should also be immutable.  In order to get your data into the class to start, you'll need to have a constructor that takes the values as arguments:

```
public class MyClass {
  String something;
  int somethingElse;

  // The class can only be modified by the constructor
  public MyClass(String something, int somethingElse) {
    this.something = something;
    this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
  }

  // Access "something".  Note that it is a String, which is immutable.
  public String getSomething() {
    return something;
  }

  // Access "somethingElse".  Note that it is an int, which is immutable.
  public int getSomethingElse() {
     return somethingElse;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does you seem to have forgotten to set the type.

```
final MyClass obj = new Myclass();
```

That means that obj can only be assigned once. Java does not have a const keyword like C++ does. If MyClass is not declared final (*final class MyClass { ... }*) it can still change.

Answer (score 0):

final variables should be assigned in the moment of declaration.

```
final MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

In java object constant means you cannot change its reference but you can change the values of its state variables untill they are not final. if all the member variables are final then its a perfect constant, where you cannot change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to wrap any object to make it "roughly" immutable.

All method calls that are not 'getters' will throw an Exception. This code defines a getter as a method that meets these criteria:

- name of the method starts with `get` or `is`
- it takes no arguments
- it returns a value (not `void` return type)

Yes, getter methods *could* mutate an object. But if your code (or code you are using) is doing that, you have some bigger problems, please go get some help :)

the code:

```
class ImmutableWrapper
    public static <T> T wrap(T thing) {
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(thing.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[]{thing.getClass()}, OnlyGettersInvocationHandler.instance);
    }

    private static class OnlyGettersInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
        public static InvocationHandler instance;
        @Override public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            final String name = method.getName();
            if ((args == null || args.length == 0)
                    && (name.startsWith("get") || name.startsWith("is")
                    && !method.getReturnType().equals(Void.class))) {
                return method.invoke(proxy, args);
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("immutable object: " + proxy + ", cannot call " + name);
            }
        }
    }
}

SomeClass myThing = ... create and populate some object ...
SomeClass myImmutableThing = ImmutableWrapper.wrap(myThing);
myImmutableThing.setValue('foo');   // throws Exception
myImmutableThing.whatever();        // throws Exception
myImmutableThing.getSomething();    // returns something
myImmutableThing.isHappy();         // returns something
```

Answer (score 0):

Mayby you can create class with final attributes. So, you can't change it: object == const.

At least "String" immutable because of it:

```
public final class String implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    private final char[] value; 
//...
}
```