# Use annotation to document parameter passing policy?

Tags: java, design-patterns, annotations, findbugs

Passing a mutable object in a method call exposes the object to modification by the callee, which may or may not be the intention of the caller, as in this example:

```
service.configure(parameters);
```

It may (1) tell the service "configure yourself with these parameters", or it may (2) ask the service "configure these parameters for me".

In the first case, you might protect the object against modification by passing a protective copy to the service (in some languages you would pass it by value). In the second case, you deliberately pass the object in the intention to have it modified. There are many possibilities, all with their pros and cons, but it always helps to clearly document your intentions.

Do you know of annotations that mark a parameter as "for read only" or "allowed to be modified? Discussion opened...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147122/how-do-i-create-a-constant-object-in-java

Comment: Yes, designing objects to be immutable is a good approach, sadly it takes a big effort to do and once done is easily broken again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In allusion to `javax.annotation.concurrent.Immutable` from jsr305, I started using a `Mutable` annotation, which means "this object is to be modified". There is no findbugs check associated with it; it simply improves the documentation. Example:

```
service.configure(@Mutable parameters);
```

Now you can see at first glance that `parameters` is subject to being changed.

Comment: I don't see `@Mutable` in javax package